# Locating Errors When Developing Android Apps

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm working on my first Android app and to be honest I'm not sure about most of what I'm doing. Right now I'm stuck on a NullPointerException that is created by a line that refers to another class that, in turn, refers to another class.

How can I locate the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **[debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging)**. If you are using eclipse, it's very easy to debug your program in most cases. Two main options in eclipse are to use the [logger](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for debug prints to logcat, or debug the program [step by step](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) to detect relevant errors. [Here](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html) is a tutorial for both options and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeSitNPAExg) is a nice video tutorial in YouTube regarding debug in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eclipse debugger to help with that.  Set a break point above the line that errors out and deploy your app using the Eclipse debugger (with the little bug icon) rather than the standard deployer (the play button).  You'll be able to see what is going on right before the line with the error occurs and hopefully fix things up.

If that doesn't work, you can post the stack trace and your method that has the error and we can take a look at it.